# How to do apache ant property expanding for a file structure within a copy task

Tags: properties, ant, expand

for using with ant, I have created a template directory structures with some common template sql scripts.

I have used property names in the directory names, file names and in the files.

For example the root directory of the template is:
   "${application.name}-Deployment-${release.buildid}"
a filename is called:
   "${application.name}_install.sql"
and there are also properties used in the sql scripts.

I like to copy this template directory with expanding all the used properties.

How can I do this, what is the best/fastest/less-code way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve my problem with the below Ant xml.

if somebody has a beter method, please put it in this threat.

```
  <target name="expand_filename">
    <loadresource property="tofile">
      <propertyresource name="file"/>
      <filterchain>
         <expandproperties/>
      </filterchain>
    </loadresource>   
    <move file="${file}" tofile="${tofile}"/>
  </target>
  <target name="start">
    <dirset id="deploy" dir="../Templates/Deploy_template">
      <depth max="0"/>
    </dirset>
    <propertyregex property="template_dir"
                   input="${toString:deploy}"
                   regexp=";"
                   replace=""/>
    <loadresource property="deploy_dir">
      <propertyresource name="template_dir"/>
      <filterchain>
         <expandproperties/>
      </filterchain>
    </loadresource>   
    <copy todir="../${deploy_dir}">
      <fileset dir="../Templates/Deploy_template/${template_dir}"/>
      <filterchain>
         <expandproperties/>
      </filterchain>
    </copy>
    <foreach param="file" inheritall="true" target="expand_filename">
      <path>
        <fileset dir="../${deploy_dir}" includes="*$*{*}*"/> 
      </path>
    </foreach>  
  </target>
```